# Left Eigenvectors vs. Right Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have a matrix $A$ and a symmetric invertible matrix $D$ such that $DA$ is symmetric. 
The right eigenvectors of $A$ are $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\cdots, \lambda_n$.
Can we use this information to derive (or estimate) left eigenvectors/eigenvalues of $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that $D$ is symmetric.

Let $x$ be an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$.  Let $y=Dx$.  Then

$$A'y = (A'D)(D^{-1} y) = DAx =\lambda Dx = \lambda y.$$

So then $y$ is an eigenvector of $A'$.

Comment: Thank you; am I right that this proof works even if $D$ is not a diagonal matrix?

Comment: Then I will update the question accordingly. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, it has to be symmetric, also!

Comment: Oh, right! Thank you, I updated the question again.